# Proving that a Normal operator with real eigenvalues is self adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-adjoint-operators, normal-operator

I came up with this solution to the problem. Does this make sense and is there a better way to going about this problem?

Let $\lambda$ be the real eigenvalue of a normal Matrix $N$. Then, $\overline{\lambda} = \lambda$. Using this and properties of normal operators:
\begin{align*}
        Nx = \lambda x &\Longrightarrow N^\ast Nx = \lambda N^\ast x \\
        &\Longrightarrow [N^\ast Nx]^\ast = [\lambda N^\ast x]^\ast \\
        &\Longrightarrow N^\ast Nx = \overline{\lambda}Nx = \lambda Nx = \lambda^2 x \\
        &\Longrightarrow N^\ast x = \lambda x = Nx \\
        &\Longrightarrow N^\ast x = Nx
\end{align*}

Now, this proves that $N^\ast x= Nx$ only when $x$ is an eigenvector of $N$. This implies that both $N$ and $N^\ast$ have the same eigenvectors. So any vector in the transformation $N^\ast$ can be represented as a linear combination of the basis consisting of orthogonal eigenvectors of $N$:

$N^\ast v = c_1Nv_1 + \dots + c_nNv_n$, where $v$ is an arbitrary vector in the vector space, $c_1, ..., c_n \in \mathbb{F}$ and $v_1, \dots, v_n$ form the basis of eigenvectors.

As all vectors in the vector space satisfy $N^\ast = N$, by definition, it is proven that $N$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Can we use the spectral theorem? That is, can we state that there exists a unitary $U$ and diagonal $D$ such that $N = UDU^*$?

Comment: And what do you deduce from $N^*x=Nx$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That by definition it is self-adjoint?

Comment: Being self-adjoint means that $N^*=N$.  You only proved that $N^*x=Nx$ when $x$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But any vector in the vector space can be written as a linear combination of the orthanormal basis of eigenvectors and so $$N^\ast x = c_1Nx_1 + ... + c_nNx_n$$, where $$x_1, ..., x_n$$ form the basis of eigenvectors and $c_1, ..., c_n$ are some scalars. Does that not prove that N is self-adjoint for all vectors in the space?

Comment: Yes, it does, but you did not mention that in your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, I've added that argument in my proof

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $N$ is normal. Then
\begin{align}
     \|(N-\lambda I)x\|^2 &=\langle (N^*-\overline{\lambda}I)(N-\lambda I)x,x\rangle \\
     &= \langle (N-\lambda I)(N^*-\overline{\lambda}I)x,x\rangle \\
     &= \|(N^*-\overline{\lambda})x\|^2
\end{align}
Therefore, if $N$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors with real eigenvalues, then $N^*$ has the same orthonormal basis and corresponding real eigenvalues. So $N=N^*$, because this is true on a basis.